# How to improve the speed of this query execution

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(sureness) FROM tweet WHERE ID in
(select DataitemID from entity_dataitem_relation  where EpochID IN 
(SELECT ID FROM epoch WHERE StartDateTime>='2013-11-01' AND EndDateTime<='2013-11-31')AND
    DataitemType=3) ;
```

And I indexed DataitemID in entity_dataitem_relation table to increase the speed. I even  indexed EpochID  to help increasing speed but still this query is very slow and it takes 2 min to be executed(it is noteworthy that I entered in a project in the middle of that so I have to continue with what others did so I dont have much flexibility in terms of design)

NB: the following part is very fast:

```
SELECT DataitemID from entity_dataitem_relation  where EpochID IN 
(SELECT ID FROM epoch WHERE StartDateTime>='2013-11-01' AND EndDateTime<='2013-11-31');
```

Another thing : even when I replace sureness with ID which is prinmary key of the table it still takes that much time
what should I do ? Is there anything that I can do to improve speed?

Comment: Which of the three queries is slow?  Try EXPLAIN, or running each one individually.  Posting the CREATE for each table will also help in the analysis.

Comment: Thanks for answering this part is very fast:SELECT DataitemID from entity_dataitem_relation  where EpochID IN 
(SELECT ID FROM epoch WHERE StartDateTime>='2013-11-01' AND EndDateTime<='2013-11-31');

Answer (score 2):

To try to reduce table scanning, you can rewrite this query using JOINS:

```
SELECT SUM(t.sureness)
FROM tweet t
JOIN entity_dataitem_relation edr
  ON edr.DataitemID = t.ID
    AND edr.DataitemType = 3
JOIN epoch e
  ON e.ID = edr.EpochID
    AND e.StartDateTime >= '2013-11-01'
    AND e.EndDateTime <= '2013-11-31'
```

Add the following covering indexes:

```
tweet(ID, sureness)
entity_dataitem_relation(DataitemID, DataitemType, EpochID)
epoch(ID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)
```

MySQL will probably still scan through all the rows in the index on `tweet`, so the more records you have in the `tweet` table, the slower this will be.

Comment: Thanks,By covering indexes do you mean I should for example index sureness in tweet table?( I know how to do simple indexing but I am wondering if covering indexes is sth different or not?

Comment: I did it as you said and I got a lot of improvment in speed but still it is not acceptable by covering index do you mean sth like this :                                                                 create index Epoch
on entity_dataitem_relation(EpochID)

Comment: @HamedMinaee, I'm hoping you'll look up the term covering index on the Internet. Those are multi-column indexes that I listed.